# Calculate time based on business working hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Add numbers of hours to a timestamp and make sure that the output is within working hours.

For example:

```
Open Time  -> 9:00 AM
Close Time -> 6:00 PM

First Date -> 12/1/2020 12:00 PM
Add Time   -> 7 hours
Result     -> 13/1/2020 10:00 AM
```

I am trying to achieve this using GAS ES5/ES6

Already tried a formula which is very close to this logic:

```
Cell A7    = First Date
Cell G5    = Add Time
Cell B1    = 9/24-18/24
Sheet2!A:A = List of Holidays to Skip
0000011    = Skips Saturday and Sunday

=if(A7,if(and(hour(A7+G$5)>9,(hour(A7+G$5)<18)),A7+G$5,workday.intl(int(A7+G$5+$B$1),1,"0000011",Sheet2!A:A)+hour(A7+G$5+$B$1)/24),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
  function myFunction() {
  
  var open_h = 9  // 24h
  var close_h = 18 //24h
  var add_h = 7 // number of hours
  
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
  next_Monday = d.getDate()
  
  var first_date = new Date() ;
  var end_date = new Date();
  
  end_date.setTime(end_date.getTime() + (add_h*60*60*1000))
  
  if (end_date.getDate()>first_date.getDate()){
    end_date.setDate((new Date()).getDate());
    end_date.setHours(23, 0 , 0);
  }
  
  if (end_date.getHours()>=close_h){
    
    if (end_date.getDay() == 5 || end_date.getDay() == 6 || end_date.getDay() == 0 ) {end_date.setDate(next_Monday) }
    else {end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + 1)} // tomorrow
 
    var end_time = end_date.getHours()-close_h + open_h
    end_date.setHours(end_time, 0, 0);
                                   }
    Logger.log(end_date) 

} // end function
```

***end_date*** will give you the desired result.

**Edit**: it also takes weekends into consideration.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, this function didn't log anything.

Comment: if the number of hours you add result in a new day then this function would not work. I need to make some changes. I assumed that you wouldn't add a number of hours that would swift the end_date to tomorrow. Namely, if now is Friday 11:23AM and you add 13 hours then you go to Saturday 00:23 AM. Then the if condition will fail since 0 < than the closing hour.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please run the script again. @eceo. Let me know if you are planning to add an amount of hours that would swift the day to tomorrow.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I coded it in such a way that if the added hours swift the today date to tomorrow date, then I change it back to today date (11PM). Which means the difference between 11 PM and 6PM is 5 hours. So it will continue into the if statement regarding the next business day with 5 hours difference. If you don't want this behaviour you can simply comment out this if part of the code: if (end_date.getDate()>first_date.getDate()) etc..